# Dishwasher ground

Tags: electrical

I am installing plug on my dishwasher.  I know how to ground the plug but I don't know what to do with ground wire coming from the unit. Do I connect both wires to the ground screw?

Comment: Where are you on this planet, and can you provide photos of the cut cord end and the plug?

Comment: The only question I would ask are you talking about the ground on the dishwasher side ? If so the ground wire should go to the frame work of the dishwasher most of the time this box on the dishwasher is metal and connecting the ground wire from the plug to the metal box or frame is the correct way to ground the system.

Answer (score -2):

**Stop what you're doing and hire a electrician!**

If you have to ask this kind of question here, then you shouldn't be messing with house wiring, *especially* with appliances that are likely to be in wet surroundings.  You are in over your head.  Have a professional do this so that you don't electrocute you or anyone else that ever walks into your kitchen.

Comment: This is a DIY site and this is a simple question! -

Comment: @EdBeal: No, it's not really all that simple.  The OP clearly doesn't understand grounding, and his question leaves too many other questions open.  The obvious answer is to connect the three wires from the device to the three terminals of the plug, but there's something else apparently going on he hasn't told us about.  Some things are not appropriate for amateurs to do.  This is one of them since the OP is missing a lot of understanding, and the consequences of getting it wrong can be quite severe.